# How to import modules into web.py templates?

Tags: python, web.py

I have following piece of code:

```
render = web.template.render('templates/')
app = web.application(urls, globals())
```

I read about template imports in the [web.py cookbook](http://webpy.org/cookbook/template_import).

Now, when I try to import `re` in a template:

```
render = web.template.render('templates/', globals={'re':re})
app = web.application(urls, globals())
```

I got an error:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /'dict' object is not callable
```

and this line showed in the traceback: `app = web.application(urls, globals())`.

But when I modify it:

```
app = web.application(urls)
```

the error is gone, and `re` is imported in my template.

I don't understand how `globals={'re': re}` in `web.template.render` breaks it?

Why I can't keep both globals as in second example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing there is something else you are doing in your script or template that is causing that error. If you showed the complete example, then it would be easier to see. Here is a working example:

```
import web
import re

urls = ('/', 'index')
render = web.template.render('templates/', globals={'re':re})
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:
    def GET(self):
        args = web.input(s='')
        return render.index(args.s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And the template, index.html:

```
$def with(s)

$code:
    if re.match('\d+', s):
        num = 'yes'
    else:
        num = 'no'

<h1>Is arg "$:s" a number? $num!</h1>
```

Browse to http://localhost:8080/?s=123 to try it.

Comment: Thanks for the example!. I found the problem accidently today when I restarted the server - the code worked. My bad.